# Displaying and Saving "time" datatype from SQL with C#?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

How do I properly displays the **"time"** datatype of MS SQL to ASP.NET MVC page? When I get the column to my class (the property in my class in of type DateTime), I call the "**ToShorTimeString()**" method but then that would displays something like this: "1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM"

I need it to be able to display as, i.e. "11:00 AM", and when making update, able to save the correct value back to the database as **Time** datatype.

Comment: The `toString` method, using a [custom format string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx) would be my first thought...

Comment: Tried ToString() but didn't work. See my responses below :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've changed that SQL column to use DateTime instead :) Why not making it easier! Thanks all for the responses.

Answer (score 1):

```
myDate.ToString("hh:mm tt");
```

Comment: I've tried that but it doesn't work. This is what currently stored in the database: **15:00:00.0000000**, when mapping to my class as DateTime object, calling **myTime.ToString("hh:mm tt")** would return this: **1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM** . In fact, regardless of what the value was stored in the database, it always returned **1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM**.

Comment: I also tried TimeSpan, when using this, it would displays all zeroes. Thanks.

Comment: Cast your variable as a varchar and use a String instead of DateTime or TimeSpan and see if the value gets assigned correctly.

Answer (score 1):

```
Timespan ts = TimeSpan.Parse("15:00:00.0000000");
DateTime dt = new DateTime(ts.Ticks);
Response.Write(dt.ToShortTimeString());
```

here you go.

```
output: 3:00 PM
```